# Retrofit Body giving null values but coming perfect in Postman

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I am trying to parse a JSON

```
{
    "CALLBACK_URL": "http://159.65.00/api/paytm/response/",
    "ORDER_ID": "yKaiv4",
    "CUST_ID": "adhish@abc.com",
    "TXN_AMOUNT": "1",
    "CHECKSUMHASH": "j7WzwAh5SFzmP4JWKx9X3mpcv6VxCenaSiWzArjdQgnblpL9YLy4Hio8tHuB2O0ZOiQ1vewsxPKd52HG9rmxYQ=",
    "WEBSITE": "WEB_STAGING",
    "CHANNEL_ID": "WEB",
    "INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID": "Retail",
    "MID": "DIY123555501617"
}
```

The above JSON I am getting in POSTMAN but when I am trying to parse the same in my Android Java code using the following POJO class, my JSONbody elements is coming as null. The POJO class is:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class PaytmResponse {

    @SerializedName("MID")
    String mid;

    @SerializedName("INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID")
    String industryTypeId;

    @SerializedName("CHANNEL_ID")
    String channelId;

    @SerializedName("ORDER_ID")
    String orderId;

    @SerializedName("CALLBACK_URL")
    String callbackUrl;

    @SerializedName("TXN_AMOUNT")
    String txnAmount;

    @SerializedName("CUST_ID")
    String custId;

    @SerializedName("CHECKSUMHASH")
    String checksumHash;

    @SerializedName("WEBSITE")
    String webSite;

    public String getMid() {
        return mid;
    }

    public String getIndustryTypeId() {
        return industryTypeId;
    }

    public String getChannelId() {
        return channelId;
    }

    public String getOrderId() {
        return orderId;
    }

    public String getCallbackUrl() {
        return callbackUrl;
    }

    public String getTxnAmount() {
        return txnAmount;
    }

    public String getCustId() {
        return custId;
    }

    public String getChecksumHash() {
        return checksumHash;
    }

    public String getWebSite() {
        return webSite;
    }
}
```

And this is how I am trying to do it in my Android code using a function:

```
private void getChecksumFromServer(String movieName, String amount) {

    RetrofitClient retrofitClient = new RetrofitClient(getActivity());
    retrofitInterface = retrofitClient.getClient().create(RetrofitInterface.class);

    Call<PaytmResponse> call = retrofitInterface.generateChecksumHash(movieName,amount,"application/json","Token "+sharedPreferencesHelper.getString(Constants.TOKEN,""));
    call.enqueue(new Callback<PaytmResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<PaytmResponse> call, Response<PaytmResponse> response) {


            Logger.d("CODE",response.code()+"");
            Logger.d("MESSAGE",response.message()+"");
            Logger.d("RESPONSE",""+new Gson().toJson(response));
            Logger.d("URL",""+response.raw().request().url());

            if (response.isSuccessful()) {


                String MID = response.body().getMid();

                String INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID = response.body().getIndustryTypeId();

                String CHANNEL_ID = response.body().getChannelId();

                String ORDER_ID = response.body().getOrderId();

                String CALLBACK_URL = response.body().getCallbackUrl();

                String TXN_AMOUNT = response.body().getTxnAmount();

                String CUST_ID = response.body().getCustId();

                String CHECKSUMHASH = response.body().getChecksumHash();

                String WEBSITE = response.body().getWebSite();


                processPayment(MID, INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID, CHANNEL_ID, ORDER_ID, CALLBACK_URL, TXN_AMOUNT, CUST_ID, CHECKSUMHASH, WEBSITE);

            } else {

                ToastHelper.showToast(getActivity(),response.message());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<PaytmResponse> call, Throwable t) {

            Logger.e(TAG, "FAILED : " + t.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

Now, the following values in my Java code is giving null values:

```
 String MID = response.body().getMid();

                String INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID = response.body().getIndustryTypeId();

                String CHANNEL_ID = response.body().getChannelId();

                String ORDER_ID = response.body().getOrderId();

                String CALLBACK_URL = response.body().getCallbackUrl();

                String TXN_AMOUNT = response.body().getTxnAmount();

                String CUST_ID = response.body().getCustId();

                String CHECKSUMHASH = response.body().getChecksumHash();

                String WEBSITE = response.body().getWebSite();
```

Where I am making the mistake? Please note that the code is 200 success and it has a body as shown in the JSON response in the POSTMAN.

Comment: `DEBUG` your application. Add break-point `Call<PaytmResponse> call = retrofitInterface.generateChecksumHash`

Answer (score 1):

The `.body()` of a response can only be read once. You should store it in a variable and read that variable multiple times instead.

Better yet: don't parse the response manually. Instead, use retrofit's gson (or other json library) parser.

Answer (score 0):

As @Tim Castelijns said, `.body()` can only be read once.
You have to do something like this

```
PaytmResponse response = response.body();
processPayment(response.getMid(), paymentResponse.getIndustryTypeId(), paymentResponse.getChannelId(), paymentResponse.getOrderId(), paymentResponse.getCallbackUrl(), paymentResponse.getTxnAmount(), paymentResponse.getCustId(), paymentResponse.getChecksumHash(), paymentResponse.getWebSite());
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging? What is in `response` after you assign it from `response.body()`?

Comment: It's giving me {} only

Answer (score 0):

So there was something else and I figured out this when I tried the same request with Volley. The Volley showed me the actual JSON response with proper keys and these keys were missing from my POJO class and so the values here was NULL.